# Двоеточие или запятая после слов "что характерно"

Tags: двоеточие

Какой знак препинания вы бы поставили вместо вопроса в предложении:

Что характерно (?) пока я находилась в числе рабов, люди из той же касты наперебой говорили мне: "Ты очень хороший эксперт!"

У автора стоит двоеточие.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. **Возможно еще тире:**

***Что характерно —** пока я находилась в числе рабов, люди из той же касты наперебой говорили мне: "Ты очень хороший эксперт!"*

Тире **заменяет** двоеточие, в этом случае отсутствует **интонационное предупреждение** (значительно увеличенная пауза с неполным понижением голоса). Пауза тоже увеличенная, но меньшей длительности.

2. **Выбираем: запятая, двоеточие, тире?**

Обычно ставят **запятую** (почти вводная конструкция), иногда **двоеточие или тире**. Но надо учитывать структуру и интонацию.

**Запятая** не подойдет из-за **структуры** предложения (мешает подчинительный союз ПОКА), поэтому какая-то увеличенная пауза нужна. Соответственно, выбираем между **тире и двоеточием.**

3. **Смотрим контекст**

Если увеличенная пауза (интонационное предупреждение, подчеркнутая остановка в речи) подходит, то ставим **двоеточие**. Присоединительное **тире** ближе к запятой, чем "затянутое" двоеточие, и в этом случае текст более динамичен.

4. **Примеры**

***Что характерно**, на рейде город кажется феерической сказкой в абрикосовой дымке, однако всякий раз, подходя к причалу, приходится разочаровываться.*

***Что характерно**: живут в одном доме, даже на одном этаже, только в разных подъездах.*

*Уничтожена! **И что характерно** ― ты это знал!*

Comment: Спасибо за подробное разъяснение. Как всегда, всё понятно и примеры хорошие!

Answer (score 1):

Если есть **предупредительная пауза**, как в предложении: ‟С беспокойством я выпрыгнул из кибитки и вижу: матушка встречает меня на крыльце с видом глубокого огорчения (П.)”, то ставится либо двоеточие, либо тире.  Об этом написано в справочнике Розенталя: там есть два одинаковых пункта в теме про тире в бессоюзных и про двоеточие в бессоюзных, сравните [пункт 3 в этой теме](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=150#pp150) и [пункт 7 в этой теме](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=151#pp151).

При **контрастной паузе** (резкая смена событий или резкая смена эмоций, и предложение после произносится более быстро) ставим тире**

> Поворачиваюсь — человек в немецкой каске (Медв.).
> Слышу – земля задрожала (землетрясение).

Обратите внимание, что многие вводные представляют из себя односоставные бессоюзные с изъяснительным отношением, как, например, в таком предложении: ‟Вероятно, они победят”, и после вводных стоит запятая. При **такой интонации** между предложениями ставится запятая. В вашем случае как раз такая интонация.

В вашем случае нет предупредительной интонации и контрастной паузы, и следует ставить просто запятую.
Наверное, могут быть ещё какие-то интонационные варианты.

**Ответ:** следует ставить запятую.

И касательно ответа Sharon. Не могли бы вы указать, откуда эти предложения в примерах в вашем ответе. Почему там во втором предложении двоеточие? Смысл этих предложений не очень понятен. Может ли вообще быть предупредительная интонация после сочетания ‟что характерно”? Не могли бы вы указать источники?